# Javascript: sort elements in array by their frequencies

Tags: javascript, arrays

There is an array whose elements are same items in random order. I want to reorder the array such that items with high frequencies appear first and then the items with the lowest frequencies appear last.

Basically, what would be the code to return the result below?

```
const a = [1,5,3,3,2,3,4,3,3,2,4,4,4];

const result = [3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,2,2,1,5];
```

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: This is *really* bad sample data, as it makes it look like a reverse sort will give the desired result, which is *not* what the question implies

Comment: @Nick I edited the sample

Comment: @RahulBhobe better to let OP edit, to ensure that my comment truly reflects what they meant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calculate the frequency and then sort the array based on the frequency:

```js
let a = [1,5,3,3,2,3,4,3,3,2,4,4,4];

const freq = a.reduce((c, v) => (c[v] = (c[v] || 0) + 1, c), {});

a.sort((x, y) => freq[y]-freq[x] || y-x);

console.log(a);
```

Comment: You can compute `frequency` using `reduce`: `const frequency = a.reduce((c, v) => (c[v] = (c[v] || 0) + 1, c), {});`

Answer (score 2):

You need to collect same values, sort by length and get a flat array.

```js
const
   array = [1,5,3,3,2,3,4,3,3,2,4,4,4],
   result = array
       .reduce((r, v) => {
           const temp = r.find(([w]) => v === w);
           if (temp) temp.push(v);
           else r.push([v]);
           return r;
       }, [])
       .sort((a, b) => b.length - a.length)
       .flat();

console.log(...result);
```

Comment: `sort((a, b) => b.length-a.length || b-a)` or `sort((a, b) => b.length-a.length || a-b)` might be better?

Answer (score 0):

You can collect a frequency map, sort it, and generate resulting array by value and frequency.

```js
const a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 3, 2, 4, 4, 4, 5];

const result = [...a.reduce((freqs, item) => freqs.set(item, (freqs.get(item) || 0) + 1), new Map).entries()]
  .sort(([, a], [, b]) => b - a)
  .flatMap(([value, length]) => Array.from({length}).fill(value))

console.log(JSON.stringify(result))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use an object to store how many times each number appears and sort the array on that basis.

```
 let a = [1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 4, 3, 3, 2, 4, 4, 4];
    
    let obj = {};
    for (num of a) {
      if (obj[num] === undefined) {
        obj[num] = 1;
      } else {
        obj[num] += 1;
      }
    }
    
    Object.keys(obj)
      .sort((a, b) => obj[b] - obj[a])
      .map((key) => Array.from({ length: obj[key] }, () => parseInt(key)))
      .flat();

/*
OUTPUT: [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 2, 2, 2, 1 ]
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function compareValues(a, b) {
  return (a.localeCompare && b.localeCompare)
    ? a.localeCompare(b)
    : ((a < b && -1) || (a > b && 1) || 0);
}
function compareValueLists(a, b) {
  return (b.length - a.length) || compareValues(a[0], b[0]);
}

function collectEqualValue(collector, value) {
  const { index, list } = collector;
  let valueList = index[value];

  if (!valueList) {
    valueList = index[value] = [];

    list.push(valueList);
  }
  valueList.push(value);

  return collector;
}
const sampleList = [5, 1, 3, 3, 2, 3, 4, 3, 3, 2, 4, 4, 4];

console.log(
  ...sampleList
    .reduce(collectEqualValue, { index: {}, list: [] }).list
    .sort(compareValueLists)
    .flat()
);
```