# How to sort a javaScript array according to his duplication count

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array with some duplicates value. I have removed all duplicates value and get his count(repeat).
Now I have to sort this data according to his count.

Example:

```
let duplicatis_data = ['a','a','b','b','b','c','c','c','c','d','e'];
```

Expected output

```
    c->4
    b->3
    a->2
    d->1
    e->1
```

There is lots of example with removing the duplicates and return the count but they did not make filter according to count. So this is not a duplicate of those questions like below.

[How to count duplicate value in an array in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19395257/how-to-count-duplicate-value-in-an-array-in-javascript)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript: sort elements in array by their frequencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64261535/javascript-sort-elements-in-array-by-their-frequencies)

Comment: Group them, turn the object into an array (`Object.entries()`) and sort that entry -> done

Comment: @RahulBhobe I want the count for that frequency as well as I mention the expected output.

Comment: @Andreas Can you please share a example?

Comment: @Mannusaraswat - See posted answer.

Comment: thanks @RahulBhobe But my question is how can I sort that data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculate the frequency and then sort the array based on the frequency:

```js
let duplicatis_data = ['a','a','b','b','b','c','c','c','c','d','e'];

   
const freq = duplicatis_data.reduce((c, v) => (c[v] = (c[v] || 0) + 1, c), {});

const result = Object.entries(freq).sort((x, y) => y[1] - x[1]);

console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```

Comment: I already get that result but my question is how can I sort that data? like{
  
  
  "c": 4,
"b": 3,
"a": 2,
  "d": 1,
  "e": 1
}

Comment: The new `result` is an array, and not an object. There is no notion of an "order" in an object.

Comment: That's fine. Thanks, you save my day.